# Jquery UI autocomplete and webservice

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

I have a ASP textbox of class `clsArtistList` placed inside a usercontrol

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="clsArtistList" ID="txtArtistList" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then I use jquery-ui-1.8.16 to create the autocomplete feature for my textbox. I copied it from http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=515 but I don't really know how it works

```
$(".clsArtistList").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "../ArtistWS.asmx/GetAllArtists",
                    data: "{ 'ARTIST_NAME': '" + request.term + "' }",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                            return {
                                value: item.ARTIST_NAME
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
```

and this is my web service

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<Artist> GetAllArtists(string ARTIST_NAME) {
    ArtistCollection coll = ArtistManager.GetAllArtists();
    return coll.FindAll(a => a.ARTIST_NAME.ToLower().StartsWith(ARTIST_NAME.ToLower()));
}
```

For your interests, my ArtistCollection is a List of artist. And an Artist class looks like this:

```
public class Artist {
    public string ARTIST_ID { get; set; }
    public string ARTIST_NAME { get; set; }
    public string ARTIST_NATIONALITY { get; set; }
    public string ARTIST_INFO { get; set; }        
}
```

But the code does not work. Each time i type, I recieve a message alert Internal Server Error

Thank you in advance. I need you helps

Comment: Is the web service running? Have you tried pointing a browser at the web service and see what you get back from it?

Comment: I tried that, the result is OK. But it's in XML format. The documentation says that the result must be in JSON. Do you know how to return JSON ?

Comment: @HoàngLâmHuỳnh: You *can* use XML but you have to parse the results on the client. What does the XML look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you receiver a server error message, I would assume the problem is not in the javascript, but somewhere on your server.

Did you try to debug your ASP webservice code?

Comment: I've debugged the service code, it's simple and OK. I also test the WS  in the browser and it's OK. But the response format is XML. Is it acceptable ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be the value you are setting url to.

Try removing the ".." from the call

```
$.ajax({ 
         url: "/ArtistWS.asmx/GetAllArtists",
```